# How to replace the string with str_replace, but string without any additional symbols in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an issue with str_replace,
I have an object which has strings `'menu-item'`, `'item'`.

All I want is to replace `'item'` with `'item new-one'`, I tried:

```
function wp_list_pages_filter($output) {
  $output = str_replace('item', 'item new-one', $output);
  return $output;
}
```

And it's working, but the problem that the function also replace `'menu-item'` string, because it includes `'item'`.

How to replace only `'item'`? If it has additional symbols the function should ignore this. The function should be universal, not depends on exact characters.

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try adding spaces on either side " item "

Comment: @MVB76 it is not working.

Comment: Based on this example a simple `if` condition would do - no need for `str_replace` at all. Do you have there a more comprehensive example that would demonstrate why you need `str_replace`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mentioned above but a simple `if` condition will solve your problem, plenty of different ways to use this solution. Inside our outside your function.
Inside

```
function wp_list_pages_filter($output) {
    if ($output != 'menu-item') {
        $output = str_replace('item', 'item new-one', $output);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Outside

```
$if ($output == 'item') {
    $output = 'item new-one';
}
```